# Glide with Map marker (Size issue)

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-glide

I am crazy to use Glide for image loading.
Tonight i was suffering with one issue i cant solve after west hours of my life. :P

so what i was try.

```
Glide
                                .with(activity)
                                .load(databeen.getModelimage()) //URL From Serverside
                                .asBitmap()
                                .fitCenter()
                                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                                        Marker mapMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(databeen.getModelName()));

                                        mapMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resource));


                                    }
                                });
```

Yes Its working.. but what is actual issue that marker load image ***too small***.
[image]

So i change something in my code with `glide`

```
Glide
                                .with(activity)
                                .load(databeen.getModelimage())//URL From Serverside
                                .asBitmap()
                                .override(markerSize, markerSize)
                                .fitCenter()
                                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                                        Marker mapMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(databeen.getModelName()));

                                        mapMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resource));

                                    }
                                });
```

yes I am Add    **`.override(markerSize, markerSize)`**

**1)**
i try

> markerSize = 50;

but problem is .override is use pixel so every device with different resolution having different size of **MARKER icon**.

**2)**
So what i decided that i change `markerSize` with **DP**(decimal pixel).

and i use `markerSize = 50 dp(after coverting to pixel)`

But still some variation In **MARKER SIZE**  in different devices.

Please suggest me something to make it `**better**`

Comment: can you show us your bitmap loaded by databeen.getModelimage()?

Comment: Thats URL from server side